# Error while implementing ApplePay and GPay on React Native app with tipsi-stripe

Tags: react-native, applepay, google-pay

I need to implement ApplePay and GPay on my react native app with tipsi-stripe
i'm doing it with paymentRequestWithNativePay
on iPhone, I'm getting an error of Missing merchant identifier though I have added it on Xcode [image: apple pay error screenshot]

on Android, I'm getting an error of Request failed neither I can add a test card for testing [image: gpay error screenshot]

Comment: This may be related to your (the user's) country in the Google Pay payment profile. Which country are you trying from? I suggest updating your country or adding a new payment profile for a different country. Visit https://pay.google.com/ and navigate to "Settings" to access payment profile information.

Comment: @Soc looks like you are right i'm using google Pakistan and Gpay is not available in my country i think so

Answer (score 3):

after putting merchant ID it is now fixed on iPhone

```
  componentDidMount() {
    stripe.setOptions({
      publishableKey: 'pk_test_MEn0wwd8i5t2949HQfjqfNsn00D8dN0Tjp', // Qirat's account
      androidPayMode: 'test',
      merchantId: 'merchant.com.showassist',
    });
```

}

on iOS we need to code this

```
const options = {
   requiredBillingAddressFields: ['all'],
   requiredShippingAddressFields: ['phone', 'postal_address'],
   shippingMethods,
};

const items = [
  {
    label: 'Whisky',
    amount: '50.00',
  },
   {
     label: 'Tipsi, Inc',
     amount: '50.00',
   },
];

 _onPressAdd = async () => {
    const token = await stripe.paymentRequestWithNativePay(options, items);
  };
```

on Android we need to code this

```
const options = {
   total_price: '0.00',
   currency_code: 'EUR',
   line_items: [
     {
       currency_code: 'EUR',
       description: 'Testitem',
       total_price: '1.00',
       unit_price: '1.00',
       quantity: '1',
     },
     {
       currency_code: 'EUR',
       description: 'Discount',
       total_price: '-1.00',
       unit_price: '-1.00',
       quantity: '1',
     },
   ],
 };


  _onPressAdd = () => {
    stripe
      .paymentRequestWithNativePay({
        currency_code: 'USD',
        total_price: '0.00',
        line_items: [
          {
            currency_code: 'USD',
            description: 'Payment',
            amount: '1.00',
            total_price: '0.00',
            unit_price: '10',
            quantity: '1',
          },
        ],
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response payment', response);
        console.log('response.tokenId', response.tokenId);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```